# How to add a corner line under a Edittext like the screenshot below

Tags: android, textview

How to add a line like screenshots below: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Its not a `TextView` its `EditText`

Comment: Hello, yes I get the line but the corner don't appear.

Comment: I think the `EditText` style which you are looking for is for older versions (Don't know which version). For newer version, its only an underline.

Comment: you can use 9-Patch file to have any line you want. Read this: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to android development. So you are asking such question. Use `EditText` and it will show automatically. And yeah in `API 21` and above it doesnot show the what you called the corners but below `API 21` it shows the corners.

Comment: Hello @dawn I'm using API 15 and no corner appear when I call EditText

Comment: I think you have compiled your code with `API 21` or above.